# awk - argc/argv doesn't give expected output while run it from a file

Tags: bash, awk

I made this awk code to print 2 name

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    for (i=0; i < ARGC; i++)
    print ARGV[i]
} inventory-shipped BBS-list
```

i expect the result to be

```
awk
inventory-shipped
BBS-list
```

but when I run it the script still want me to write something on it to print even though the list I expect to print already there. But when i write it from terminal like this

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
        for (i=0; i <ARGC; i++)
        print ARGV[i]
}' inventory-shipped BBS-list
```

i can print the expected result.

Comment: file names can't be a part of the script. remove `inventory-shipped` and `BBS-list` from your script and run it like `./script.awk  inventory-shipped BBS-list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a shebang to execute awk from a shell script, just call it:

```
#!/bin/env bash

awk '
BEGIN {
    for (i=0; i < ARGC; i++)
    print ARGV[i]
}
' inventory-shipped BBS-list
```

That will give you much more flexibility over how to separate shell script parameters into awk variables and awk file names or do anything else you like.

Comment: That *does* cost you a set of quotes though, yes? Generally a fair price to pay for the added flexibility, but a cost nonetheless.

Comment: As in you can't use `'`s inside the script? Yes, you have to use `\047`s instead. Agreed!

Answer (score 1):

You can't put command-line arguments inside the script. You should run it as

```
./scriptname inventory-shipped BBS-list
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this

#### script.awk

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    for (i=0; i < ARGC; i++)
    print ARGV[i]
}
```

#### run script

```
chmod a+x script.awk
./script.awk inventory-shipped BBS-list
```

#### output

```
awk
inventory-shipped
BBS-list
```